# How to get a Memory Address (Pointer) from a Number Literal?

Tags: c, literals, void-pointers

Background:

I have decided to work with neutral void pointers (void*)
in my programme because it is uniform, efficient and I can
cast them to whatever is needed in the context.

When calling a comparison function, all arguments/parametres
have to be handed over as void pointer, for example:

```
compare_integer_equal((void*) &r, p12, (void*) NUMBER_1_INTEGER_STATE_CYBOI_MODEL);
```

The integer constant is defined globally as:

```
static int NUMBER_1_INTEGER_STATE_CYBOI_MODEL_ARRAY[] = { 1 };
static int* NUMBER_1_INTEGER_STATE_CYBOI_MODEL = NUMBER_1_INTEGER_STATE_CYBOI_MODEL_ARRAY;
```

Problem:

Such constants do exist for all frequently used numbers and sum up
to a file size of more than 2 MB, which I would like to eliminate.
Of course I could always use a local variable like:

```
int i = 1;
compare_integer_equal((void*) &r, p12, (void*) &i);
```

But I would like to avoid this extra effort/memory/time
when having to do hundreds of comparisons.
When trying to get a reference from a literal as shown
in the following example, the compiler produces the error:
"lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand":

```
compare_integer_equal((void*) &r, p12, (void*) &1);
```

Is there a way to get a memory address (pointer) from a Literal?
Are there other ideas to handle literals as (void*)?

Comment: I suppose if you are throwing away all type safety by using void pointers you may as well also throw away any memory efficiency by forcing your literals to be lvalues. You could make them volatile to reduce CPU performance.

Comment: @stark Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to declare a `static const` object of the proper type having the proper value, and pass its address.  While C99 added a convenient syntax for compound literals, it will generate less efficient machine code than the approach using `static const`, and will also yield the address of an object whose lifetime will be limited to the immediate enclosing block, meaning that any persisted pointers to the object will be left dangling.  By contrast, any pointer to a `static const` object will remain valid throughout the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. This is what I am actually doing right now (only the "const" is missing).

Comment: But one problem remains: For each and every number there has to be a constant defined which leads to huge source files and compiled binary files.

Comment: @ChristianHeller: One would only need to define static const objects for values one actually uses, and the cost of the code to pass the address of a const object, plus the cost of the cost object, would almost always be less than the cost of code needed to set up a temporary object of automatic duration.  The real shame is that C99 made compound literals objects of automatic duration instead of treating them like strings.